# How do I disrupt a SparkSession connection to test a try catch?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code:

```
def create_spark_session(app_name: str = "test") -> SparkSession:
      try:
        spark = (
          SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name).config("<config_1>").config("spark.excludeOnFailure.task.maxTaskAttemptsPerNode=3").getOrCreate()
        )
        return spark
      except RuntimeError as ex:
        print(f"Failed to create a spark session. Error: {ex}")
        raise RuntimeError from ex
```

I want to somehow disrupt the connection so I can test that this function retries the connection 3 times, then enters my exception (prints "Failed to create a spark session..." etc.). But I have no idea how to do this.

I have tried using unittest.mock with side_effect but I can't get this to do exactly what I want e.g. show it reattempts to connect three times and then enters and prints Exception. I can only get it to test that the connection "Timeout".